# Sync a Gitlab repository to the /dags folder of a Google Cloud Composer

Tags: gitlab, google-cloud-storage, airflow, gitlab-ci-runner, google-cloud-composer

I would like to sync a repository hosted on Gitlab to the DAGs folder in the GCS bucket created by Google Cloud Composer such that every time something is pushed to master, the bucket is updated. However, to my surprise I wasn't able to find a very elegant solution for this online.

The Google SDK has a function for syncing two repositories:

```
gsutil rsync [OPTION]... src_url dst_url
```

However, this only syncs the two folders once. I would like it to sync every time that something is pushed to the master branch.

I found two ways of doing this:

- Building a Webhook from the Gitlab repository to Google Build and then updating the GCS Bucket from Google Build. [Source](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/build-hosted-repos-gitlab)
- Creating a Pipeline in Gitlab CI/CD with a Job which starts a Containers with SDK and uses the `rsync` command to sync the the repository to the Bucket.

Both of these solutions seems not very straightforward to me. Is there a standard or better way of automatically syncing Gitlab to Google Cloud Composer?

Comment: There is no better integration with Gitlab for now.

Comment: DId you find anything? I found [this](https://engineering.adwerx.com/sync-a-github-repo-to-your-gcp-composer-airflow-dags-folder-2b87eb065915) solution but I'd be happy to hear from you if you got a different resolution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a Git-Sync container syncing, the GCS to a GCS bucket mounted via GCS-fuse. This is a bit of overkill, but I think this might be an option that could be easily deployable as a K8S deployment for example.

Both are available as reusable containers and it should be rather easy to deploy and configure access for them.

There are however some caveats - GCS Fuse (And generally GCS as backend for DAGs) has some performance problems for example when you have big number of dags (Git Sync performs atomic updates where it swaps symbolic links after sync is complete, and if you are using GCS Fuse that means that all those files will have to re-uploaded to GCS (and then re-downloaded by Composer).

There was a request to do non-atomic updates but I think it's been solved by just providing webhook when sync is completed. Maybe it can be used as well to fire off some other way of syncing than GCS Fuse: https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync/issues/53

I think ideally it would be to ask Composer team to add different mechanism to sync dags. Git-Sync is one of the best methods I think there is for DAG syncing. And it works best with temporary storage - it does not require to use GCS as a backing storage, it does not even require persistence and DAGs can effectively be kept in tmpfs even, so it has numerous advantages, unfortunately it is not supported (yet I think) by the composer deployment.

BTW. I recommend you create a request for Composer team to add Git-Sync support :)